# Como adicionar uma scrollbar a uma janela com um label usando tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Eu queria saber como posso fazer para adicionar uma scrollbar a uma lista que estou fazendo no tkinter, para a lista estou usando um label e quero saber como faço para configurar ela de modo que funcione, vou mostrar como está até agora:

````
    def listar_produtos(self) -> None:
        self.conectar() #conecta-se ao banco
        #criar janela 4
        self.janela4 = Toplevel(self.janela)

        #Configuração da janela 3 (Listar Produtos)
        self.janela4.title('Listar produtos')
        self.janela4.geometry('500x400')
        self.janela4.config(background='#fff')

        #Botões da janela 3 (Listar Produtos)
        texto_lista_produtos = Label(self.janela4, background='#fff', text='Lista de produtos no estoque')

        #Empacotamento dos Widgets do botão adicionar produto
        texto_lista_produtos.pack()

        #scroll bar
        sb = Scrollbar(self.janela4)
        sb.pack(fill=Y, side=RIGHT)

        #Selecionar e printar os produtos do banco de dados
        for i in self.conexao.execute("select * from gerenciamento"):
            if (i) is None:
                print('')
            else:
                lista_produtos = Label(self.janela4, background='#fff' ,text=(f'Id: {i[0]} | Nome: {i[1]} | Quantidade: {i[2]}'), anchor='w')
                lista_produtos.pack()```
````

Answer (score 0):

para resolver essa questão eu criei uma lista dessa forma:

```
#Cria uma lista que irá receber o valor produtos
        self.lista = Listbox(self.janela4, background='#fff', bd=0)
        self.lista.pack(side=LEFT, expand=True, fill='both')
#Verifica se a lista está vazia, se tiver irá ser inserido o texto "A lista está vazia" a lisbox e caso tenha algum dado será adicionado a lista todas as linhas da tabela do sqlite3
        comparar_valor_lista = self.conexao.execute('select * from produtos').fetchall()
        if len(comparar_valor_lista) == 0:
                self.lista.insert(END, 'A lista está vazia!!') 
        for lista_de_produtos in self.conexao.execute('select * from produtos').fetchall():
                self.lista.insert(END, f'Id: {lista_de_produtos[0]}  |  Nome: {lista_de_produtos[1]}  |  Quantidade: {lista_de_produtos[2]}  |  Preço: R$ {lista_de_produtos[3]}  |  Data: {lista_de_produtos[4]}/{lista_de_produtos[5]}/{lista_de_produtos[6]}')
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).